# Can't find the local-name content by xPath through the browser's inspection tool

Tags: xml, xpath, browser

sorry if this is a very stupid question. I'm starting to getting to know xpath and is trying to learn what certain functions mean. For example, below is the XML example I got from this website https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/xml/xpath/xpath-local-name-example/

```
<cr:cricketers xmlns:cr="http://www.example.com/">
    <cr:cricketer type="righty">
        <name>MS Dhoni</name>
        <role>Captain</role>
        <position>Wicket-Keeper</position>
    </cr:cricketer>
    <cr:cricketer type="lefty">
        <name>Shikhar Dhawan</name>
        <role>              Batsman</role> 
        <position>Point</position>
    </cr:cricketer>
    <cr:cricketer type="righty">
        <name>Virat Kohli</name>
        <role>Batsman</role>
        <position>cover</position>
    </cr:cricketer>
    <cr:cricketer type="righty">
        <name>Shami</name>
        <role>Bowler</role>
        <position>SquareLeg</position>
    </cr:cricketer>
    <cr:cricketer type="lefty">
        <name>Zaheer Khan</name>
        <role>Bowler</role>
        <position>FineLeg</position>
    </cr:cricketer>
</cr:cricketers>
```

When I search by xpath `//*[local-name()='cricketer']` or `//*[local-name()='cricketer']/name` from the chrome's developer tool, no result at all(screenshot below). Is there anything that I did wrong? 
[image]
Thank you very much!

Comment: The screenshot suggests that you've somehow wrapped this XML inside an HTML wrapper. This tends to distort things, because the HTML DOM does strange things with namespaces.If you want to learn about XML and XPath, running things in the browser isn't a good idea.

Comment: Thank you @michaelKay you are absolutely right. I've found another tool to test the xpath now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

As @MichaelKay mentioned in comment this seems to be a Chrome issue since local name does not include namespace specificator. However the following method worked for my Chrome instance (v60.0.3112.101 64-bit Windows build):

`//*[local-name()='cr:cricketer']`

[image]

**However**: Your xpath is canonically correct. You should consider that specific only if you run that xPath as a locator for, say, Selenium tests which you run against Chrome and possibly some other browsers which could have problems since html is likely not-wellformed xml.

If you take that xml from your example and try to parse in IDE (e.g.: IntelliJ IDEA) you will get the results you expect:

[image]

Comment: Seems quite wrong. The local name of an element will never contain a colon. If this works in Chrome, then it's a serious bug.

Comment: @MichaelKay It really does. V. 60.0.3112.101 64 bit windows build.

Comment: Seems that we're actually looking at an HTML document with an XML island here, where XPath often produces strange results (for example, namespaces aren't properly recognized in HTML DOM). However, I'm still rather shocked that comparing the result of local-name() to a name containing a colon should ever return true: it's a fundamental property of the XPath data model that local names are NCNames (no-colon names).